# Basic algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I am in a class higher than this, so I am embarrassed to be having a problem with this:

**The problem:**
Multiply: $(z-7)(z+3)(z-4)$

I am going to label each group to make my explanations more clear.

.................A..........B...........C

Multiply: $(z-7)(z+3)(z-4)$

**My work:**
(A)(B) = $z^2-4z-21$

(B)(C) =$ z^2-z-12$
(A)(C) = $z^2-11z+28$

Thus: $z^2 -4z-21+z^2-z-12+z^2-11z+28 $

So I get: $z^6-16z+5$

Comment: Incidentally, though it doesn't matter to the problem, $$AB+BC+AC=3z^2-16z-5.$$ This is because $$z^2+z^2+z^2=1z^2+1z^2+1z^2=(1+1+1)z^2=3z^2$$ and $$-21-12+28=-(21+12)+28=-33-(-28)=-(33-28)=-5.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just multiply the first two, take the simplified result, and multiply that by the third. Just as you would with $2\times 3\times 4$.

The answer to your problem is a third degree polynomial, not a sixth degree polynomial.

Comment: I will try that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You want $ABC$. Instead you've calculated $AB+BC+AC$ which most certainly is not $ABC$.

Instead take $AB$ and multiply by $C$:

$$(AB)C = (z^2-4z-21)(z-4) = (z^2-4z-21)z+(z^2-4z-21)(-4)$$ $$= z^3-4z^2-21z-4z^2+16z+84
=z^3-8z^2-5z+84$$

Of course, $(BC)A$ or $(AC)B$ will yield the same answer since polynomial multiplication is associative and commutative. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way of doing it:

$1. \,\,(z−7)(z+3)(z−4)$
$2. \,\,(z-7)(z^2-1z-12)$ [It was $(z-7)(z^2-4z+3z-12)$, not anymore]
$3. \,\,(z^3-z^2-12z-7z^2+7z+84)$
$4. \,\,(z^3-8z^2-5z+84)$

This should be your answer: $(z^3-8z^2-5z+84)$

**English explanation:**
1. The first step is to write down your problem.
2. Multiply the last two pairs and ignore the first pair. You should first get $(z-7)(z^2-4z+3z-12)$ by doing **FOIL** (first, outside, inside, last).
3. Multiply the first pair with the new pair you just created. Simply multiply z with each value in the new pair, and then multiply 7 with each value in the new pair.
4. Simplify.